# How can I validate an email account without leaving the checkout process?

Tags: e-commerce, email, validation, checkout, accounts

Aside from the standard process in which someone receives an email to validate an account/registration to finish a signup process, is there any alternative/best practice that retains the user within the checkout? I mean, I am trying to avoid the user leaving the checkout to go to the inbox and then returning to the app again.

How can I validate an email account without the user having to leave the checkout process?

Comment: i would ask why do you need to do this mid checkout? its interrupting the user with something essentially unnecessary to them mid goal completion, not to mention that it will effect your conversion rate

Comment: Toni took the words out of my mouth. Why not leave registration/validation until after the order has been placed?

Comment: Thanks for your help and responses. Yes, I was thinking about leaving the validation as a final step, so we can say we are aligned as UXers :)

Comment: I understand something like this will affect conversion rate. But if the user places the order with a wrong email, how will he be able to track the delivery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you validate an email address, you are checking two things:

1. Is this a valid email?
2. Does this user have access to this email?

The only way to do 1. is to send an email, and check that it doesn't bounce.  And the only way to do 2. is to send an email with some information and check that the user received that information. That can either be done by sending a code that the user has to copy and paste (not so user friendly), or by sending a link with a code, that the user can select (better choice).

So, no.  T**here is no way to validate an email account without a person checking their email.**